# How to update values within class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a class separate from the main class and I want it to keep track of balance and number of items I buy coming from the main class. However, I'm having trouble updating the Num and balance every time I make a transaction and it keeps giving me 0 and 2000 when I print balance and num.

```
class Wallet:

    def __init__(self, Num = 0, balance = 2000):
        self.Num = Num
        self.balance = balance

    def addNum(self, c, d):
        if d > self.balance:
            return print(f'You have insufficient balance to buy {c}')
        else:
            self.balance -= d
            self.Num += c
            return Wallet().print()

    def print(self):
        print(f'You have {self.Num} of {self.balance}')


Wallet().addNum(3, 30)
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of `Wallet` first. Then call the instance method `addNum(3, 30)`. That is, first `my_wallet = Wallet()`, then `my_wallet.addNum(3, 30)`.

Comment: Also, instead of `return Wallet().print()`, it should be `return self.print()`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Wallet().print()` with `self.print()`, otherwise you are creating a brand new Wallet every time you try to print it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems like the balance and num refreshes everytime I run it within a while loop. Is there a way to keep each run saved?

Comment: @tec3719 what, exactly are you doing? Are you doing `Wallet().addNum(3, 30)` in a while-loop? Because again, **that creates a new instance each time**.

Comment: The same applies to `Wallet().addNum(3, 30)`: it creates a new Wallet every time you do that. Try `wallet = Wallet(); wallet.addNum(3, 30); wallet.addNum(1, 17); wallet.print()`.